# Does Django caches payload deserialization

Tags: django, caching, django-views, payload, django-middleware

Using Django==2.2.13, djangorestframework==3.8.1

I am looking into doing some work in a middleware on incoming requests.
A part of the work is to deserialize the payload and check if it has some content (key/value).
The Django view is deserializing the payload downstream.

I have a few questions:

1. Will Django cache my payload deserialization, or will it do it again in the view regardless?
2. If Django does not cache the deserialized payload, is there any way to enable it to do so?
3. Does the deserialization process take longer when done in the view, vs the middleware?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

1. Not as default.
2. You can use [Django's cache framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/cache/) to store the payload for some time.
3. Deserialisation should be handled by the [DRF serializers](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/), time performance should be similar, but having it there instead of the view is a much cleaner approach.

Comment: @Horatio What do I need to set up or enable to get the payload cached? I don't need it cached for long, since the View is hit immediately after the middleware